# Copy excel tables into powerpoint boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I used to know a feature in powerpoint that allowed the following:

- copy an row of e.g. 4 excel cells
- select 4 boxes in powerpoint
- paste the content of the cells into the text of the 4 boxes

I'm not looking to paste a table or a single text box, rather that the content of cell 1 is pasted into box 1, cell 2 in box 2 etc.

I can't seem to find this back online or with any of my usual trial and error attempts.

Anybody familiar with this feature and how to use it?

Edit:

Here's some screenshot of how it works with me

Copy from excel

[image: Copy from excel]

Select 4 text boxes and paste into powerpoint

[image: Select 4 text boxes and paste into powerpoint]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine with a normal `ctrl`+`V`.

Comment: Doesn't work with me ... I'm using excel and ppt 2010 ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after re-installing office and after some testing on my own and with other computers, found that the ability to copy a range of Excel cells into multiple text boxes/shapes was due to a powerpoint add-in (Think-Cell) I had previously installed.

The normal action when copying a range from Excel to PowerPoint is to paste it as a table, even if you have several shapes selected.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use. I did not code it, credits to the author:

```
Sub ConvertTableToTextboxes()

  Dim slide As slide
  Dim shape As shape
  Dim i As Integer

  ' Loop through each slide in the active presentation
  For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
      ' Loop through each shape on the slide
      For Each shape In slide.Shapes
         ' Check if the shape is a table
         If shape.HasTable Then
             ' Loop through each row in the table
             For i = 1 To shape.Table.Rows.Count
                 ' Loop through each column in the table
                 For j = 1 To shape.Table.Columns.Count
                     ' Get the text from the cell
                     Dim cellText As String
                     cellText = shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

                     ' Create a new text box at the same position as the cell
                     Dim textBox As shape
                     Set textBox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, shape.Left + shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.Left, _
                         shape.Top + shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.Top, shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.Width, _
                         shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.Height)

                     ' Set the text box text to the cell text
                     textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cellText

                     ' Remove the cell from the table
                     'shape.Table.Cell(i, j).shape.Delete
                 Next j
             Next i

             ' Remove the table shape
             'shape.Delete
         End If
     Next shape
 Next slide
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).